# Error:UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character" to get data in usable format for histograms

Tags: r, select

Here is my code,

```
library(ade4)
library(factoextra)
library(magrittr)
library(textshape)
library(describedata)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
bw.phen <- "BWphenology"
#select the columns you want to find correlations between
##columns must be numeric
as.numeric_version(BWphenology)
bwphenselect <- select(bw.phen) %>%
  
select(bud_break_jul, first_pistil_jul, last_pistil_jul, first_pollen_jul,
         last_pollen_jul, percent_overlap, flower_type, harvest_date_jul, 
         harvest_date_d.a.d., season_length)

#find correlations
cor(na.omit(bw.phenselect))
```

I keep getting the error in use method select error and have tried importing the data from text and base, manually setting all columns in the data set to be numeric, as well as using the as. numeric function. What else could I Try?

Comment: `object 'BWphenology' not found` Voting to close as not reproducible. Read [MCVE]

Comment: You maybe are looking for `bwphenselect <- get(bw.phen) %>% select(bud_break_jul, first_pistil_jul, ....)`

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't related to the data types in your data, it's this line:

```
bwphenselect <- select(bw.phen)
```

`select` needs two arguments - a dataframe, and a column list.  You're only giving it one.  Usually the dataframe is piped in from a previous line, like this:

```
iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length)
```

which is the same as `select(iris, Sepal.length)`.

It's not clear from your code what your dataframe is called, but assuming it's `BWphenology`, you probably want something like this:

```
bw.phenselect <- BWphenology %>%
  select(bud_break_jul, first_pistil_jul, last_pistil_jul, first_pollen_jul,
         last_pollen_jul, percent_overlap, flower_type, harvest_date_jul, 
         harvest_date_d.a.d., season_length)
```

The data type conversion is a different problem.